# Radiotray repository?

Tags: internet-radio

Are there any internet radios on the ubuntu software manager apart from Gradio which never opens and keep crashing. And I also couldn't find radiotray in there, which I have on my Mint OS. Is there a repository which has the latest version that will work on 17.10?

let me know, thanks.

Comment: Please try `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get install radiotray` on terminal.

Comment: Is it work ? Do you able to install it successfully ? I'm going to create new answer if that work.

Comment: Hi I didn't try your method, What I did is I went to github which has this version Radiotray-NG v0.1.8 https://github.com/ebruck/radiotray-ng/releases/tag/v0.1.8 which also happens to have the 17.10 compatible version. Cheers

Comment: I could try your method, and give you the feedback - if you like :)

Comment: Glad you have solve  it, its up to you whether to try.

Comment: @sans -  `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install radiotray`

Comment: @ravery - whoops, I missed the `update` command. Sorry :( pardon my ignorance

Comment: Hi, tried uninstalling this NG version by terminal but wont work. And I cant uninstall from the software manager since it cant even find it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Radiotray its available on 17.10, to be precise in [`universe`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) repository. So simply install from terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe ###if you haven't enabled it yet.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install radiotray
```